# Radio button ng-model to true/false (checked/unchecked)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind a radio button to true when the radio button is selected and to false when the radio button is not selected. I must be missing something really obvious because I haven't been able to do it yet.

I have a simple collection, eg:

```
$scope.collection = [
    { id: 1, selected: true},
    { id: 2, selected: false},
    { id: 3, selected: false}];
```

And I wish to bind the "selected" property to whether the radio button is checked or not. Sounds simple enough but ng-model binds to undefined. ng-checked almost works, it displays the correct result but never actually updates the value...

[Plunkr with the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/pkhGhXdzvnUIi6wdgC9N?p=preview)

Comment: It sounds simple except that you're trying to make radio buttons act like check boxes. You'll probably have to use ng-change to update the values of selected on the controller.

Comment: I tried to make ng-change work, but since it depends on ng-model I couldn't get a positive result. I implemented some logic with ng-click to bypass the problem but I feel that this problem is so simple that it must have a simple and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the radio buttons to the right object fields in from the controller `$scope`:

```
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])

.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.radioContent = [
        {txt: 'One', checked: false},
        {txt: 'Two', checked: false}
    ];
    $scope.$watch('radioContent', function (now, then) {
        console.debug('Something changed', now);
    }, true);
}]);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="radio in radioContent">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio.checked">{{radio.txt}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuech495/)

Comment: That example doesn't really work very well. I edited your fiddle and forked it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ppb2yg7y/

As you can see I changed one the checked values to true and added a text with the checked value, for debugging. The initial state of the radios are incorrect (none are selected) and the ng-model sets the undefined value. Sure, you get the change event but in console.debug you also get the value as undefined... I could force-change the values in the watch function but it doesn't feel like this would be the right approach. Is there no clean 2-way databinding way? :\

Comment: @CosmeBenito thanks, but it was only meant to be a quick example about how to bind using `ng-model`.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort, but it isn't actually binding since the outcome is always undefined :P I had gotten to this point but "refuse" to believe this is the optimal way.

Comment: @CosmeBenito I don't think there's a better way than this: http://jsfiddle.net/t4grd50a/ and that doesn't work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but maybe this is one of the places AngularJS tries to do too much 'magic'?

Comment: I don't know, I tend to avoid $scope.$watch unless it's absolutely necessary. I created a variable bound to the currently selected object and created a ng-click function to update the previously selected radio (to false) and the clicked radio (to true). It works but feels non-angular.

Comment: Well, the `$scope.$watch` there was just for the `console.debug` to show any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ng-bind and ng-selected don't work that well with radio buttons, but if you change the radio buttons to be checkboxes, the code works as expected.

And using @Ashesh's answer, the radio.checked property of a button still becomes undefined after messing with the radio button once.

[Working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PnxysZJYFnfeVblEc7ms)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*"
            data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5"
            src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module("sampleapp", [])
      .controller('samplecontroller', function($scope,$rootScope) {
        $scope.collection = [
          { id: 1, selected: true},
          { id: 2, selected: false},
          { id: 3, selected: false}];
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="sampleapp" ng-controller="samplecontroller">
    <div class="radio" ng-repeat="element in collection">
      <span ng-bind="element.id"></span>
      <span ng-bind="element.selected"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" ng-model="element.selected">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if you change the selected property into `true` or `false` and **NOT** `"true"` or `"false"`, it works.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, I do not wish to give the user the idea that he can select more than one option.

Comment: After playing with my fiddle, it seems that upon clicking on a radio button, the item.selected property simply vanishes from it.

Comment: Yes, because ng-model is binding to undefined.

Comment: @mutlei i want the same answer like this, but instead radio button